# LFTP --exclude prevents log file creation

Tags: ftp, lftp

Is there a way to use advanced features like --exclude and still keep xfer:log-file "lftpbackup.log" capabilities?  I read manual at http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man-alt.html also lftp.yar.ru wiki, tutorial, and example links.  I also searched unix.stackexchange.com and askubuntu.com for lftp posts that mention : xfer:log-file "" capabilities are lost when --exclude or other advanced features are used.

```
set -a | grep "log" (edited log related items) 
set log:enabled no
set log:file ""
set log:level 9
set log:show-ctx no
set log:show-pid no
set log:show-time no
set xfer:log-file /media/root/7CBAA4537758FCA/SAVE/rsyncTEST-usb/2/lftprsyncTEST.log
set xfer:make-backup yes
set xfer:max-log-size 3M
```

This generates lftprsyncTEST.log logfile in /media/root/7CBAA4537758FCA/SAVE/rsyncTEST-usb/2

> ftp ftpd@192.168.1.133:~> mirror -R /media/root/7CBAA4537758FCA/SAVE/rsyncTEST-usb/2/ /luksftpmnt/SAVE/rsyncTEST-usb/rsyncTEST-usb/3copy > lftprsyncTEST.log
>
> Total: 1 directory, 3 files, 0 >symlinks
>     New: 3 files, 0 symlinks
>     2709 bytes transferred

```
set -a | grep "log" (edited log related items)
set log:enabled no
set log:file ""
set log:level 9
set log:show-ctx no
set log:show-pid no
set log:show-time no
set xfer:log-file /media/root/7CBAA4537758FCA/SAVE/rsyncTEST-usb/2/lftprsyncTEST.log
set xfer:make-backup yes
set xfer:max-log-size 3M
```

This does NOT generate lftprsyncTEST.log logfile in /media/root/7CBAA4537758FCA/SAVE/rsyncTEST-usb/2

> lftp ftpd@192.168.1.133:/> mirror -R --exclude sub2-1/ /media/root/7CBAA4537758FCA/SAVE/rsyncTEST-usb/2/ /luksftpmnt/SAVE/rsyncTEST-usb/rsyncTEST-usb/3copy > lftprsyncTEST.log
>
> New: 2 files, 0 symlinks
>   2548 bytes transferred

only example of an attempt i could find was (but unsure if it actually worked since it pipes after lftp quits and from above examples log files are created simultaniously to transfering files - at least the log file is created tho maybe not populated until lftp finishes)
https://www.mail-archive.com/lftp@uniyar.ac.ru/msg04426.html